# What is the LaTeX template used in this lecture note?

Tags: templates

Note that there is a symbol which looks like "$" in the first screenshot, it might be a transformation of "s", and the content is made up of hyperlinks in the second screenshot. I like this kind of font especially, appreciate if you could help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you have that PDF file the `pdffonts` utility or your pdf viewer can show you the exact fonts used, no need to make us guess from an image

Comment: Regarding the s-like symbol, that's backboard bold, not a `$` sign.  Regarding the general fonts question, the other comments address that.

Comment: To reproduce the style in the table of contents, use `\usepackage[linktoc=section,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` (should work regardless of the document class). Note that, in general, `hyperref` has to be the last package  that you load in the preamble.